# 'this' is undefined inside the foreach loop

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

I am writing some typescript code and iterating an array. Inside the loop, I am trying to access 'this' object to do some processing as:

```
console.log('before iterate, this = ' +this);
myarray.days.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    console.log('before transform, this : ' + this);
    this.datePipe.transform...
});
```

but this fails, as it complains that 'this' is undefined 
'this' object prints correctly as [object object] before/outside the loop, but inside the loop, it is undefined. Why is that? And what is the fix for that?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You need to either use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
myarray.days.forEach((obj, index) => {
    console.log('before transform, this : ' + this);
    this.datePipe.transform...
});
```

Or use the [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
myarray.days.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    console.log('before transform, this : ' + this);
    this.datePipe.transform...
}.bind(this));
```

The reason is that when passing a regular function as a callback, when it is invoked the `this` is not actually preserved.
The two ways which I mentioned above will make sure that the right `this` scope is preserved for the future execution of the function.

Comment: Nice explanation..

Answer (score 17):

Add the `this` as a parameter for callback.

Adding `}, this);` instead of `}.bind(this));` should resolved issue in Angular.

Thus, should look like:

```
myarray.days.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    console.log('before transform, this : ' + this);
    this.datePipe.transform...
}, this);
```

Comment: Sometimes SO frustrates me and most of the times it helps in my problems as this..

Comment: Excellent, love this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myarray.days.forEach( (obj) => {
    console.log('before transform, this : ' + this);
    this.datePipe.transform...
});
```