# How to fix ‘Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined’ error in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have a bug, but I don't know what else to do to fix it. Below is my code and the error:

```
courses: any[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.locale = this.localeService.currentLocale();
    this.user = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
    this.userService.getCoursesInProgress(this.user.id).subscribe(courses => {
        this.coursesInProgress = [];
        courses.forEach(n => {
            const courseObj: Course = new Course(n);
            this.coursesInProgress.push(courseObj);
        });
    });
    this.userService.getCoursesFinished(this.user.id).subscribe(courses => {
        this.coursesFinished = [];
        courses.forEach(n => {
            const courseObj: Course = new Course(n);
            this.coursesFinished.push(courseObj);
        });
    });
}
```

> TypeError · Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: is the courses array defined? It doesn't look like its defined.

Comment: The API is returning `courses` as `undefined` or `null`. Please see the browser's network tab to check what its returning. Alternatively, you can use `console.log(courses)` to see whats returned.

Comment: Sidenote, you could write `this.coursesInProgress = courses.map(n => new Course(n))`

Comment: The error tells you that you're trying to use `forEach` on `undefined` (and contains the line number where the problem is). Your code uses `forEach`on `courses`. So that means that `courses` is undefined. `courses` is the event emitted by the observable returned by one of your service method calls (the line number indicates which one it is). So that means that the service doesn't return an observable emitting an array of courses as you think, but instead emits `undefined`. You haven't posted the service, so we can't help more.

Comment: See how I deduced where the problem is by just carefully reading the error message and the code. You should be able to do the same.

Comment: I already try this and it didn't return `null` on the contrary it shows my arrays

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724426/this-is-undefined-inside-the-foreach-loop

Comment: when you log out courses is there any data, can you provide an example of the data inside courses array?

Comment: I thought that this would be obvious after my comment, but apparently it's not: since the problem is in the service, if you want us to help more, you need to post the code of the service, because we can't read it if you don't post it.

Comment: Your user is async so it is not retreived when you call getCoursesInProgress(you don't have user.id in that moment).

Comment: Thank you everyone, my problem is solved