# Cannot read property setState of undefined while trying to set the state in my React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from an API and setting it into the state by the `setState` method, but I am getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
>       at products.jsx:263

The code is:

```
getDetails () {    
    var subjectfinal = [];
    let relatedsub = JSON.parse(subjects.related_subjects);
    relatedsub.forEach(function(item, index) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("subject_id", item.value);
        fetch("https://***********/get_subject", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            subjectfinal.push(responseJson[0])
            console.log(subjectfinal) //gives me the subject data i,e array contaning 3 objects in it
            this.setState({ subjectstobedisplayed: subjectfinal }),()=>console.log(this.state.subjectstobedisplayed)) // gives error
            )
        })
        .catch(error => {
            swal("Warning!", "Check your network!", "warning");
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
};
```

I want to ask the if `console.log(subjectfinal)` I am getting all the data then why at time of setting state it gives me error?

Comment: Paste the html code as well.

Comment: Also checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context

Comment: does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724426/this-is-undefined-inside-the-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this,

Change your getDetails function definition to arrow function syntax

```
getDetails = () =>  {
  ... all the above code
}
```

OR in constructor, bind this to getDetails function

```
this.getDetails = this.getDetails.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the forEach second argument `this`. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
relatedsub.forEach(function(item, index) { //... }, **this**);
```